# How to handle multiple reviews on several merge requests?

Tags: git, gitlab, merge-conflict-resolution

I have worked on a GitLab repository for several months. In my institute students have to wait for a supervisors review in order to be able to merge into main. My Reviewer did not have time for several weeks, that is why I have several open merge requests for different features.

I created a branch "branch-1" and later a merge request "merge-request-1" (branch-1->main).
In order to preserve the changes from "branch-1" I branched "branch-2" from "branch-1" and later created "merge-request-2" (branch-2->main).
I than branched "branch-3" from "branch-2" and created "merge-request-3" (branch-3->main).

Now I finally have comments on all 3 merge requests and I wonder what would be a "clean" workflow to integrate the review. While mostly the merge requests deal with their own files there are some files that are changed by 2 or all 3 of them.

I also wonder whether it was a good idea to branch not from the main branch but from the feature branches.

I am grateful for any suggestions.

I haven't tried anything so far.
I thought about integrating the changes as a commit only in the latest merge request or alternatively integrating them in the respective merge requests, but I feel like this could create chaos.

Comment: Do they depend on each other? If that is not the case, you can "disconnect" them by using a simple rebase. For example, for `branch-3` you could do `goit rebase --onto origin/main branch-2 branch-3`..... the PRs the way you created is probably wrong because given that you are targetting main branch, the PR is including changes from `branch-1` and `branch-2`.... when you do the rebase and foece-push to replace the old branches when the changes from the _other_ branches will disappear from each PR.

Comment: well... not `goit` but `git`, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "depend on each other". I branched them off of each other.

Answer (score 2):

My experience leads to the following practices:

- **Don't branch off a branch.**  While it initially seems attractive, it can easily and rapidly turn into a mess.  With two branches being behind main the process of keeping them up to date and also in sync with each other becomes messy and hard. I've seen this becomes a mess many times and enough times to recognize that is is a bad pattern to use.
- **Frequently merge or rebase main**, i.e. make sure main is up-to-date and then merge main into your feature branches and resolve differences. Do this frequently enough to make merge differences small. Actual frequency will depend on your code base activity.
- **Short-lived branches.** Ideally branches are around for a few minutes, hours or days at the most.  Once you are over a week merge and conflict problems will increase greatly - depending on how much work is being done on the repo.
- **Avoid 'merge branches'** where you merge multiple branches into one and then merge that one into the main branch.  It adds complexity and when code change issues are complex they are hard to do correctly and then are hard to understand when looking at history.
- **Break down work.**  If work seems like a large change break out pieces and get them in one by one. Otherwise you are more likely to have long lived pull requests with hard to resolve merges.

In your specific situation I would merge the branches one by one.  As each one is merged look at the next one and see if it has merge conflicts that need to be resolved before merging it.

Comment: I agree on most points, except that I have no problem placing one branch after the other.... the only catch (and it is a **big** one here.... and probably the main reason why the question was raised in the first place) is that **you need to know how to handle them individually**... that is when there is a rebase of a branch that you started off from (**specially** if the base branch is not yours).

Comment: Thank you very much for the general remarks on a clean workflow. I also tried to keep the merge requests small and do them frequently. However when you depend on someone else's work it might not suffice to keep the frequency high.

I will try now merge the branches one by one.